# How do I make sure my printer prints the fonts I see on screen? (PDFs, Overleaf, Mac)?

Tags: fonts, pdf, mac, overleaf, printing

I'm using the following setup:

- Mac OS 10.15.4
- Brother MFC-L5750DW (latest driver)

And have several PDFs (both old and new) which I'd like to print.

The old PDFs were made in Lyx years ago and printed on my last printer perfectly.

Now the PDFs (old and new) do not print like they look on-screen fonts:

On-screen:
[image: The on screen perfection]

On paper:

[image: The on-paper rubbish]

What I'd like, please, is guidance as to how I can solve this.

When I view a sample document in Adobe Viewer, I can see information about several "user defined" fonts, this information doesn't show up in Preview, which I normally use.

From distant memory, my last printer printed the files correctly after upgrading CUPS.

I tried this this morning and have had no success.

What else do you need to know to help me? What can I do?

The sample PDF I generated from Overleaf just now has the same issue :(

What to do, what to do?

Thanks!

**Update**

1. Printing the older PDFs now results in success (suspect something to do with Ghostscript?)
2. Re-PDFing the old Lyx files results in success (great!)
3. The PDFs I download from Overleaf.com result in failure.
4. Possible workaround - download the source from Overleaf, re-ecode with Lyx (?), enjoy working PDF?

Which leads no to Question 5:

How would I then send a PDF to someone and be sure that it would print as I expected? What have I missed or what setting should I toggle?

Comment: Looks like the fonts aren't embedded in the PDFs and are missing on your system

Comment: Or the fonts are installed, but Ghostscript (used by Postscript printer drivers) is unabled to find them because they are not in the search path or in the wrong format. Or the fonts are not installed, the PDF viewer substitutes them with a good replacement font, and Ghostscript does not know about this replacement and replaces instead with some unsuitable default font. Inspecting the file might help, if you make it available somewhere. Knowing how you set the font (in your new document for example) might help as well, i.e., a small minimal example document.

Comment: In the meantime you can always bake some ginger cookies and eat them to enjoy your day despite the printing problems :)

Comment: Hi there, this is Tom from Overleaf support. Overleaf is set up to embed all font characters used in the document (this is the default anyway for LaTeX), so I suppose that the printer is not picking up the fonts from the PDF file. The three basic things to try is (1) finding a different driver for your printer; (2) printing from a different software; (3) re-encoding the PDF file using e.g. Ghostscript, Adobe Acrobat, some Print to PDF tool etc.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. I (think I) installed Ghostscript this morning, how would I go about checking the search paths? If I inspect the file, how much detail do I need and what should I look for? I experimented this morning with a file from Overleaf, which parts should I inspect/change? I will, in the meantime take Tom's suggestion of re-encoding the file (if I can). Marjin's suggestion is also good…

Comment: I'm making progress! The latest version of Lyx used ps2pdf to make me a PDF with GPL Ghostscript 9.23 (God! It almost sounds like I know what I'm talking about!) which printed  my old files perfectly. Later I'll try the new ones.

Comment: @Marijn ooh cookies

Comment: In the terminal you can type `gs -h` to find the search path for fonts (at the end of the output of this command). For inspecting the file you can use `pdffonts`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420994/os-x-pdf-get-font-information for instructions for Mac. Besides the regular `pdffonts yourfile.pdf` you should also try `pdffonts -subst yourfile.pdf`. And an MWE would still be helpful. (if it is still needed of course, from your last comment it seems you are close to a solution already).

Comment: @Marijn - sorry, no luck. The cake (not cookies) was delicious, but the newly downloaded Overleaf PDFs (can one download source files from Overleaf?) print „wrong“

Comment: One can definitely download source files from Overleaf (Menu-Download Source at the top left corner), but copy-and paste from the editing window also works fine. Make sure that the file is minimal, so the smallest possible complete file that reproduces the problem. Just one line of text would probably be sufficient to reproduce the issue, so you don't have to share all your secret recipies with us :)

Comment: Thanks, I‘ll take a look and report back

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same issue and for me the fix was rasterizing the pdf using the following Python script:

```python
import fitz

zoom = 5.0
mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom, zoom)  # zoom = parameter
source = fitz.open('/path/to/your/pdf/file.pdf')
target = fitz.open()
for page in source:
    pix = page.get_pixmap(matrix=mat)
    tarpage = target.new_page(width=pix.width, height=pix.height)
    tarpage.insert_image(tarpage.rect, stream=pix.pil_tobytes("PNG"))
target.ez_save('target.pdf')  # targetname = parameter
```

This way, the printed document looks exactly the way it appears on your screen. Unfortunately, performing the rasterization is admittedly a little cumbersome.